# What are and Where to find officially the list of `nivo slider` animation options?

Tags: jquery, animation, slider, nivo-slider

[`Nivo Slider`](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) is great for image sliding.

I google for `list of nivo slider animation options` but no helpful results I get.

So the question is:

What are and Where to find officially the **list of `nivo slider` animation options**?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/) It's at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Great! That's what I want. How did you find that?

Comment: I just googled `jquery nivo slider` and it's the first result under `jquery plugin usage`.

Comment: to:john `sliceUpRight sliceUpDownRight sliceDownRight` are NOT in the list, why?

Comment: I don't know why the creators didn't add those to the list, but you're right. They should still work since they're in the source code though.

Answer (score 1):

See [this page here](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/).

The options are listed in the fourth code block

Comment: to:danwellman `sliceUpRight sliceUpDownRight sliceDownRight` are NOT in the list, why?

Comment: to:danwellman Great! That's what I want. How did you find that?

Comment: Just by looking around the site :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for settings they are in **`jquery.slider.js`** on line # 637 onwards

Answer (score 1):

on the Nivo Slider Website -> [Documentation](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation) -> jQuery Plugin Usage you will find this on the bottom of the page:

The Nivo Slider has plenty of options to fiddle with. Below is an example of the code with all available options and their defaults:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation
        controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
</script>
```

The effect parameter can be any of the following:

```
sliceDown
sliceDownLeft
sliceUp
sliceUpLeft
sliceUpDown
sliceUpDownLeft
fold
fade
random
slideInRight
slideInLeft
boxRandom
boxRain
boxRainReverse
boxRainGrow
boxRainGrowReverse
```