# Animation options as `sliceUpRight sliceUpDownRight sliceDownRight` are NOT in the `nevo slider` list, why?

Tags: jquery, animation, slider, nivo-slider

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603888/what-are-and-where-to-find-officially-the-list-of-nivo-slider-animation-option?answertab=votes#tab-top), the official place where we can find (NOT via associative google search) is at [this nivo's site](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/).

Though, we cannot see `sliceUpRight sliceUpDownRight sliceDownRight` in the list - they are valid options indeed.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an oversight in the documentation as they are present in the source, and work correctly.

It's worth noting though that `sliceUpDownRight` is not included in the routine which randomly picks a transition.

My guess would be that these transitions are recent additions, and the documentation simply hasn't yet been updated.